# How can I add Unicode character in status text by using Tweepy?

Tags: python, unicode, tweepy

I want to update status with the Chinese text `我` for which the Unicode is `U+6211`. I do the same thing when I add emoji in status `("\U0006211")` but it didn't work. So is it possible to update the text that is not English?

The error that I got:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-8: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: \U requires 8 hex digits

Answer (score 0):

when I use print("\u6211") it prints the correct character but as a "?" so it should work if you have the font I think

Answer (score 0):

> The \U escape sequence [...] expects eight hex digits

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code

You're providing 7 instead of 8 digits. You can simply append an extra 0: `"\U00006211"`
Alternatively, you can use the `\u` excape sequence: `"\u6211"`